# libGDX get information out of Blender empty objects

Tags: java, dictionary, libgdx, blender

I have a map made in blender and I want to get information out of the empty objects like the cube's dimensions and position or even the curve's path .
I mostly want the cube's information to use with libGDX's BoundingBox for simple collisions , but I think because the empty has no faces , the BBox can't wrap around it .
Is there way to use empty objects , or do i have to use normal cubes to create the boxes and not render them ?
I export the files to fbx and then convert them to g3db format .